# Docker File Alternatives to Latest?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I was told it's better not to use `latest` in Docker File, but how can I find alternatives?

According to: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop the latest version of ubuntu is `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` but when I go to: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/tags I see strange tags like: `bionic` what is that?

and `22.10` this is a future version? how is that possible?

and while I could fine `22.04` I could not find `22.04.1`

Comment: these are codename. check this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems involving the usage of **latest** tag on a docker image. The application is constantly changing and with it its architecture as well. While pulling an image with the `latest` tag, you use these changes as well. This may be good in a personal project sometimes but in a large scale application, you dont want your application to change drastically. Example:

- While working on a dockerized application, we incorporated db connector to session storage redis db, the connector connected to redis at the start of the application and if it was unsuccessful, the application would not start. Every update/change on the host machine with running application meant deploying redis as well as we were using the **latest** tag.

22.04 Ubuntu is the latest LTS build, but there also is experimental 22.10 (ref. [Ubuntu 22.10](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/08/ubuntu-22-10-release-new-features)